# Why is the determinant of a $2\times2$ rotation matrix equal to $1$?

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, graphing-functions, rotations

I've seen [Why is the determinant of a rotation matrix equal to 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503047/why-is-the-determinant-of-a-rotation-matrix-equal-to-1)

I do get that no matter what value you put for theta you will end up getting $1$, but I would like to explain it using the cos and sin graphs (do some reasoning based on graphs).

I think there might be a way to proof this using the graphs.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use a graph to show that the determinant of $\left( \begin{matrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & - \cos \theta \end{matrix} \right)$ is $1$?  I suppose you could plot $y=\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)$

Comment: @Henry How would that show that the determinant is 1?

Comment: Have you taken trigonometry? By the way, @Henry you have a typo in the second column of your matrix. The minus sign should go with the sine, not the cosine.

Comment: When you rotate an object, its image is congruent to its original. Think about that for a moment

Comment: Well! I believe you know $\theta$ matrix but that is not what you want but the geometrical/intuitional thought for the same, is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general form of a $2 \times 2$ rotation matrix is:

$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\  
\sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix}$

By definition, the determinant of this matrix is $\cos^2{\theta} + \sin^2{\theta}$. This is equal to $1$ by the [Pythagorean trigonometric identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity).